# Laravel pattern validation pipe character issue

Tags: regex, validation, laravel

Using the Laravel framework I need to check the value of a submitted field against a set of valid values.

The problem is Laravel uses the | character to separate validation rules belonging to a field.

This does *not* work, it throws a

> "preg_match: No ending delimiter '/' found":

```
'my_field' => 'match:/^(value1|value2|different value|yet another)$/'
```

How does one escapes the `|` character in this case if the `\` character does not help?

Comment: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/pull/1139

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The answer, essentially, is that you cannot use a pipe if you're specifying all the rules in one string like you're trying to do. The pull request that m.buettner mentioned was closed. However, Tayler Otwell mentioned an alternative method you can use: specify the rules in an array. An example of this would be:

```
$rules = array(
    'field' => array('size:5', 'match:/foo|bar/')
);
```

Comment: Excellent! I did not know about this alternate method which looks much better to me than fumbling around with long strings.

Comment: it saved me! in laravel 4

Comment: It's obvious when you step back & look that | is being used to separate the rules, but not when you're just focusing on the `regex:/value1|value2/` that the | is already in use!

Comment: Better than a official documentation!

Answer (score -1):

After using array() ,regular expression pattern needs to be enclosed in /.../ to avoid **preg_match(): Unknown modifier '|'** error