# Laravel3 Validator: the "match:" rule is not seeing the closing delimiter. Is it a bug?

Tags: regex, laravel, validation, laravel-3

We have a content type which has been confirmed to match this regex:

- `/([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2}[+]{1})/`

When trying `'match:"/([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2}[+]{1})/"'`, L3 throws a *"no ending delimiter '/' found"* exception.

Am I doing something wrong, or is there a limitation in L3 I'm bumping up against, or is this a bug??

Comment: By the way out input regex can be simplified to `/([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2}\+)/`.

Comment: Take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875334/laravel-pattern-validation-pipe-character-issue

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Thanks for that link. That looks like it should work. Thanks-a-bunch!

Comment: @rekire Thanks ... I knew there was a more succinct solution, but didn't know exactly how to get there. Thanks again.