# Issue with Laravel Rules & Regex (OR) operator

Tags: php, regex, laravel

I'm having a small issue with my Laravel rules and regex operation :

Basically a rule is an array as such :

```
'room'=>'required|alpha_num|min:2|max:10',
```

The problem i'm having is when using regex and the | (or) operator such as :

```
'cid'=>'required|regex:/^((comp)|(soen)|(engr)|(elec))\d{3}$/i',
```

I'm getting a server error saying :

```
ErrorException

preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found
```

I'm guessing the `preg_match` is stopping at the first `|` inside the `/.../`.

Is there anyway to write the above code to make it work ?

Full code :

```
public static $rules = array(

'cid' => array('required', 'regex:/^((comp)|(soen)|(engr)|(elec))\d{3}$/i'),

'description'=>'required|regex:/^[A-Za-z \t]*$/i|min:3|unique:courses',

'credits'=>'required|regex:/^\d+(\.\d)?$/'

);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel pattern validation pipe character issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875334/laravel-pattern-validation-pipe-character-issue)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

http://laravel.com/docs/validation#rule-regex

> regex:pattern
>
> The field under validation must match the given regular expression.
>
> **Note:** When using the regex pattern, it may be necessary to specify rules in an array instead >of using pipe delimiters, especially if the regular expression contains a pipe character.

To clarify:
You would do something like this

```
$rules = array('test' => array('size:5', 'regex:foo'));
```

Comment: I checked that but i'm not really sure what it means , then rulesare already inside an array : public static $rules = array(
 
 'name'=>'required|regex:/^((Comp)|(Soen)|(Engr)|(Elec))/i',
 
    'cid'=>'required|regex:/^((comp)|(soen)|(engr)|(elec))\d{3}$/i',
 
    'credits'=>'required|numeric'
 
    );

Comment: Edited my answer to clarify how to use an array.

Comment: been struggling with multiple validation rules including regex for about an hour, and this saved me.

Answer (score 9):

You should use an `array` instead of separating rules using `|`:

```
'cid' => array('required', 'regex:/^((comp)|(soen)|(engr)|(elec))\d{3}$/i')
```

The pipe (`|`) sigh is available in your regular expression pattern so it's conflicting with the separator. Other answer already stated it.

Comment: Hi , i tried the code above but getting error (full code in main post) :  
BadMethodCallException

Method [validateRequired|regex] does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

I use this style and save my life :-)

change code from

```php
    $validator = Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
        [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'initial_credit' => 'required|integer|between:0,1000000|regex:/[1-9][0-9]*0000$/'
        ]
    ]);
```

to

```php
    $validator = Validator::make(
    $request->all(),
        [
        'name' => 'required|string',
        'initial_credit' => [ // <=== Convert To Array
            'required',
            'integer',
            'between:0,1000000',
            'regex:/([1-9][0-9]*0000$)|([0])/' // <=== Use pipe | in regex
        ] // <=== End Array
    ]);
```