# Regular expression validator accept number with decimal numbers 0 or 5 in range 0-5

Tags: regex

I'm trying to write a Regular Expression validator to accept numbers only with decimal part 0 or 5 only and in range 0-5 . for example:

```
-1          false
-.5         false
-0          false

000000      true
0.0         true
0000.       true
0           true
.50000000   true
00001.      true
01.50       true
2.00000     true
2.5000      true
03          true
03.5        true
0004        true
0004.5000   true
00005.0     true

0           true
0.5         true
1           true
1.5         true
2           true
2.5         true
3           true
3.5         true
4           true
4.5         true
5           true

1.05        false
5.5         false
10          false
20          false
30          false
40          false
50          false
```

No matter how many 0 in front or behind the numbers it can be valid.

I tried this one `^[0-5]+(?:\.[05]0?)?$` but it fails on cases: `0000.`, `.5`, `001.` and `5.5`

Many thanks!

Comment: What should it return for `55.0`?

Comment: Yes, I want to discard any decimal number which is not .5 or .0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```
^0*(?:[0-4]?(?:\.5?0*)?|5(?:\.0*)?)$
```

Explanation:

```
^0*                  # allow leading 0s
    (?:              # non capturing group
        [0-4]?       # below 5: number starts with 0-4
        (?:\.5?0*)?  # optional: decimal dot, might be followed by one 5 and 0s.
    |                # or
        5(?:\.0*)?   # 5, possibly followed by 0s
    )
$
```

Be aware this also validates an empty string or a single `.`. Tell me if that's an issue, as a quickfix you can add looks ahead at the beginning to check the length and content: `(?=.)(?!\.$)`.

See [demo here](http://regex101.com/r/nQ3gM8).

Comment: I am a newbie in regex Thanks for the explanation! @Robin

Comment: @Robin could you know how to put this regex in php preg_match()? It said " ErrorException: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found"...

Comment: You have to put the pattern inside `/... /` delimiters: something like `preg_match('/regex/',...) `. I can't post much code now but there's a code genrator on regex101 (middle left) that should be useful.

Comment: Thanks, I tested on preg_match('/^0*(?:[0-4]?(?:\.5?0*)?|5(?:\.0*)?)$/', '5') which is fine. However, I got the exception on Laravel validation. Maybe I found the solution in other way.

Comment: @ChrisSo I'm not familiar with Laravel but the regex contains a `|`, could [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596587/issue-with-laravel-rules-regex-or-operator) be your issue? Also FYI, inline code formatting for comments is done with backticks `\``

Comment: @Robin Yeah I fixed this by using arrays to contain different validation constraints since the regex consists of "|"

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following:

```
^0*5(?:\.0*)?$|^0*[1-4]?(?:\.[05]?0*)?$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/uB6dI6)**

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
^0*([0-4]?(\.[05]?0*)?|5(\.0*)?)$
```

http://rubular.com/r/bDM7mOHL54

Comment: Be careful as this also validate `40`: the `\.` has to be here when the decimal digits are matching

Comment: oops, however I just want 0-5 range

Comment: It still validates `500` :) Also, remember `(0|5)` is `[05]`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another one:

```
^0*(([0-4]?(\.5?0*)?)|(5(\.0*)?))$
```

[image]