# Laravel Validation - number must start with 0 (zero)

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

How to do input validation that a number must start with 0?

For example:

```
$rules = [
    'full_name' => 'required|min:6',
    'number' => 'required|numeric|min:5',
];
```

On the  `number` field, it is requred, must be numberic only and minimum of 5 digits. I also need to include rule that it must start with 0?

Comment: I think you'd need to use the Laravel Regex Validation?

Comment: Does the number come as a string or an integer?

Answer (score 4):

Use laravel `regex:pattern` validator, inside an array ([Issue with Laravel Rules & Regex (OR) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596587/issue-with-laravel-rules-regex-or-operator)) and a regex of something like this: `/^[0][0-9]{4,}/`

Comment: I don't see any other validator that would validate a leading zero. You could write a custom validator tho.

Comment: It's a quantifier meaning: 4 or more, with leading zero that is 5 or more. Google for: regex quantifiers. I am no regex pro so don't believe me 100% what I say.

Answer (score 1):

You can try it with

```
substr(Input::get('number'), 0, 1);
```

as data field and the rule

```
'in:0'
```

But as php will cut leading zeros if you are transmitting the number as int, it will most likely be hard. If it's a number as string, it will work.