# How to validate form request for date?

Tags: laravel

The value of day has to be a number

The value of day from 1-9 has to be

01,02,03,04,05,06,07,08,09

The value of day are numbers 01-31 (Because there are up to 31 days in a month)

```
'day' => 'required|date_format:"d"',
```

I tried doing this, but when the day is 1, it still passes. When it's supposed to fail.

Comment: [This old question suggests regex to enforce leading zeros](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28094604/243245), although I don't know Laravel well enough whether you can do the date validation too. You could certainly write a regex to limit to 31 though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laravels `date_format` validation [uses PHP `date_parse_from_format` method](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse-from-format.php) which accepts an integer without leading zeros for 'd'

You can either write a custom date format function or you could add `min:2` to your rule as a quick fix.

eg.

```
'day' => 'required|min:2|date_format:"d"',
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go the regex route to accomplish this since the format requires a leading zero:

```
'day' => 'required|integer|max:31|regex:[0-3][0-9]'
```

This way you're expecting two digits and those two digits won't exceed 31 days in a month.