# Regex validation user or admin

Tags: php, regex, validation, laravel, laravel-4

Working on a regex to validate that the input could either be user or admin, and its required to fill in one of those:

```
'user_type' => 'regex:/^\buser\b|\badmin\b$/|required'
```

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: The regex is not validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the syntax is correct, there is one definite error in your regex: The start-of-string anchor `^` is only tested for `user`, and the end-of-string anchor is only tested for `admin`. And if you have those, you don't need word boundary anchors.

Try this:

```
'user_type' => array('regex:/^user$|^admin$/')
```

Comment: @aelor: Unless the `^$` are completely unnecessary because the framework forces the regex to match the entire input, the original regex would match `user` in the input string `"user name"`, so the regexes do differ.

Comment: I get this error with the regex: preg_match(): No ending delimiter '/' found

Comment: @user3185936: Well, there is an ending delimiter in the regex, so probably the syntax for declaring a regex in Laravel is different than the one you're using. The docs I found online are a bit sketchy, but it seems the `|required` part is wrong. Can you try the edited version?

Comment: @user3185936: Ah, I've found the problem. The `|` operator is confusing the Laravel parser, it seems. Details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12875334/laravel-pattern-validation-pipe-character-issue.